# Multiple Scatter Charts Loop for different X and Y values

Tags: excel, vba, loops, charts, series

I was trying to create a Macro for multiple charts (loop) using multiple series (different X and Y value). For a sart I used only two series of X and Y values and everything went well with the first series of X and Y values as can be seen here:

The first range of values:

VB:

```
Set myRange1 = Range(.Cells(c, 1), .Cells(c + 27, 1)) 
Set myRange2 = Range(.Cells(c, 2), .Cells(c + 27, 2))
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZADVj.png

But, then I got a different result for the next range of values. In a nutshell, for some reason the series were divided into another two not following the range that I have defined by this code:

VB:

```
Set myRange3 = Range(.Cells(c, 3), .Cells(c + 27, 3)) 
Set myRange4 = Range(.Cells(c, 4), .Cells(c + 27, 4))
```

The result can be seen in this picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/75onu.png

Here is the code that I used:

```
Sub loopChart_M() 

    Dim myChart As Chart 
    Dim MultiRange1 As Range 
    Dim MultiRange2 As Range 
    Dim MultiRange As Range 
    Dim myRange1 As Range 
    Dim myRange2 As Range 
    Dim myRange3 As Range 
    Dim myRange4 As Range 
    Dim c As Integer 
    c = 1 


    While c <= 120 '1=dataSource1, 4=dataSource2, 7=dataSource3
         'set data source for the next chart
        With Worksheets("CM_AXIAL") 
            Set myRange1 = Range(.Cells(c, 1), .Cells(c + 27, 1)) 
            Set myRange2 = Range(.Cells(c, 2), .Cells(c + 27, 2)) 
            Set MultiRange1 = Union(myRange1, myRange2) 
            Set myRange3 = Range(.Cells(c, 3), .Cells(c + 27, 3)) 
            Set myRange4 = Range(.Cells(c, 4), .Cells(c + 27, 4)) 
            Set MultiRange2 = Union(myRange3, myRange4) 
            Set MultiRange = Application.Union(MultiRange1, MultiRange2) 

        End With 


         'create chart
        Sheets("CM_AXIAL").Select 
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select 


        With ActiveChart 
            .ChartType = xlXYScatter 'xlLine
            .SetSourceData Source:=MultiRange, PlotBy:=xlColumns 'sets source data for graph including labels
             ' you can chage the columnd and rows ploting modes using ActiveChart.PlotBy = xlRows or  ActiveChart.PlotBy = xlColumns
            .SetElement (msoElementLegendRight) 'including legend
            .HasTitle = True 
             'dimentions & location:
            .Parent.Top = c * 14 'defines the coordinates of the top of the chart
            .Parent.Left = 0 'defines the coordinates for the left side of the chart
            .Parent.Height = 400 
            .Parent.Width = 429 
             '.ChartTitle.Text = "Title here"
             'ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
             ' ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""CM"""
             'ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Name = "=""Geometry"""







        End With 


        c = c + 29 




        With ActiveChart 


             'chart name
            .HasTitle = True 
            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Activate 



            .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "Diagonal " ' & c
             'X axis name
            .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True 
            .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Element length (m)" 
             'y-axis name
            .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True 
            .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Axial force(KN)" 
        End With 






    Wend 


End Sub
```

Comment: Make sure to qualify `Range()` with the worksheet too, `.Range(.Cells()...`.

Comment: Can you make your problem/question more obvious?

Comment: The ranges that I defined are for the first Range: A1:A28 (for X value) and B1:B28 ( for Y value) and for the second Range: C1:C28 and D1:D28. Everything is fine with the first range, but with the second one I obtained(after running the Macro) two series for some reason that are A1:A28 with C1:C28 and A1:A28 with  D1:D28